# Truthy and falsey value as the initial value for useState not being reflected properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, boolean, react-hooks

I want to use a query result as the initial value for `useState`.

```js
const {data, loading, error} = useQuery(GET_INFO)
const [value, setValue] = useState(Boolean(data.result && data.result.token))
```

I only care if the initial value is truthy or falsey, meaning if the token variable has any kind of string in it, then I want it to be considered `true`. If not, `false`.

When I do `console.log(Boolean(data.result && data.result.token))`, I get the proper `true` or `false`.  I get the same result when I do `console.log(Boolean(!!data.result && data.result.token))`.

However, when I check `console.log(value)`, I'm always getting `false` no matter what `Boolean(data.result && data.result.token)` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching the data is asynchronous, so you need to wait for the data to be returned before setting `value`.

Use the `useEffect` hook, as this is exactly what it is designed for:

```
// Initialize to false.
const [value, setValue] = useState(false)
// Begin fetch.
const {data, loading, error} = useQuery(GET_INFO)

// Everytime data changes, this hook will run.
useEffect(() => {
    if(data && data.result) {
        setValue(!!(data.result && data.result.token))
    }
}, [data, setValue])
```

The `useEffect` will run when `data` changes, meaning that when your query returns `data`, `setValue` will be called.

See the [React docs on hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).